# Best technique to built an ejectable drawer?

Tags: motion

I want to build a closet with ejectable drawers. On the top should be 4 buttons, each eject opening one of the four drawers of the closet.

I am looking for ideas on how to accomplish this. What kind of springs, slider mechanisms perhaps, and other materials to use?

Any examples?

Comment: When you say "eject" do you just mean to open the drawer fully? "Eject" to me means to launch it out of its rails, as in "ejection seat."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need only to eject the drawer automatically and can close it back manually, I would suggest using compressed spring which would push out the drawer if there is no resistance. 
A hook or similar mechanism holds the spring when the drawer is pushed back in.

This mechanism would save you use of motors, and thus you won't use electricity. The drawer would function even in case of power outage.